# python does not recognize no-background option in imgkit

Tags: python, pdfkit, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

I want to get an image of html elements with no background. this code below does it but it does adding white background. (I have images as elements there so I cant just remove the white background.):

```
import imgkit
kitoptions = {
    # some random options:
    'zoom': 6, 
    "enable-local-file-access": None,
    'quality': 100,
    # this option doesn't work and causing crash (what I need):
    'no-background': None
}
imgkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.png', options=kitoptions)
```

so I want to use the 'no-background' thing but it doesn't recognize it.
it seems that there is 'no-background' attribute there, but here it seems that there is:
[list of options](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

error is:

OSError: wkhtmltoimage exited with non-zero code 1. error:
Unknown long argument --no-background

Comment: If someone will face this in the future, that's probably only pdfkit option and not imgkit.

Comment: turns out that the option I meant for is: "transparent": "". this works really nicely.